# Extraer valores de consulta SQL y compararlos con variable PHP

Tags: php, mysql, bucle-for, condiciones

Tengo este código,bastante sencillo,pero es que no me puedo dar cuenta cómo resolverlo..he probado de todo sinceramente.

Tengo que extraer una serie de números,enteros de una columna de sql. La columna se llama "numeroReservado".

Lo que quiero hacer es traer esos valores, compararlos en un For, detectar cuales son, para "borrarlos". Es decir,dentro de un For de <=300, detectar los números reservados, ej:50,20,34,67 y poder compararlos en un if para poder decidir si quiero imprimirlos ó no (que luego serán volcados en un option select). Me explico? Muchas gracias desde ya. Les dejo el código.

```php
<?php
include 'conexion.php';

$numerosReservados = mysqli_query($conectar,'SELECT numeroReservado FROM datos');


for ($i=0;$i<=15;$i++) {
    
    while ($filas=mysqli_fetch_array($numerosReservados)){

    $res = $filas["numeroReservado"];
        //echo "<pre>";
        //var_dump($res);
        //echo "</pre>";

    if ($res != $i) {
    echo $i;
    }

}
```

Este código me está devolviendo ésto.."00001234567891011131415"

Luego de un tiempo decidí bajar la cantidad de datos mostrados y por eso reduje a 15 los números a imprimir por el FOR, pero la idea es que sean aprox. 300.

Créanme que he dado con distintos resultados,pero aún no logro lo que necesito.

Comment: los valores de los numeros reservados ahora mismo son "3,8 y 12". Y en este código,sólo me quita el 12 (último elemento).

Comment: Tu pregunta no se entiende. Hablas de *detectar los números reservados, ej:50,20,34,67 y poder compararlos en un if para poder decidir si quiero imprimirlos* pero no explicas **cuál es el criterio para decidir si el número debe imprimirse o no**... Es más, puedes filtrar los datos mediante la consulta SQL con algo como `... WHERE numeroReservado NOT IN(50,20,34,67)`, evitando así traer datos a mansalva, para luego desechar parte de ellos. No tiene sentido y el código no estaría optimizado, a no ser que necesites los demás datos en otro bloque de ese mismo contexto.

Comment: Son enteros. 3,8,12,etc...

Comment: Lo que tengo que hacer es Generar numeros del 1 al 300,por ejemplo; y cuando llegue a uno de los numeros reservados (ej:12),lo deje de lado y prosiga generando numeros desde ahi,me explico? Basicamente es para que alguien que va a reservar un número,no vea los números que ya han sido reservados,cuando salgan mediante HTML en un option. se entiende? Gracias por su tiempo y disculpen, recién estoy empezando je.

Comment: Tienes razon, ha sido un fallo de mis lentes, jeje, que se me rompieron hace una semana y veo las cosas a medias aun con las nuevas :-)

Comment: *Lo que tengo que hacer es Generar numeros del 1 al 300,por ejemplo; y cuando llegue a uno de los numeros reservados (ej:12),lo deje de lado y prosiga generando numeros desde ahi* ... Tu comentario me deja más confundido... ¿Qué sentido o relación tiene eso con respecto a una consulta SQL? Quizá lo que necesites es una columna de tipo AUTOINCREMENT en tu tabla ¿? No sé, suena a intento de reinventar la rueda.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pruébalo así mejor:

```
<?php
include 'conexion.php';

$numerosReservados = mysqli_query($conectar,'SELECT numeroReservado FROM datos');

$array_reservados = [];

while ($filas = mysqli_fetch_array($numerosReservados)){
    $array_reservados[] = $filas["numeroReservado"];
}

for ($i = 0; $i <= 15; $i++) {
    if (!in_array($i, $array_reservados)) {
        echo $i;
    }
}
```

Donde lo que hacemos es primero agrupar el resultado en un array ($array_reservados) y después, durante el **for** comprobamos si los elementos están en dicho array, y si no lo estan los volcamos a la salida con el **echo**.

Comment: Genio! Funcionó a la perfección! Te debo una,tu próxima duda,me la dejas a mi si? jajajaja. Gracias a todos los que colaboraron y/o se tomaron un tiempo en ver y revisar el código.

Answer (score 0):

Si quieres solamente los números que no sean: `50,20,34,67` puedes indicarlo en la misma consulta SQL usando [`NOT IN()`](https://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-basics/mysql-not-in/):

Por ejemplo:

```
<?php

    include 'conexion.php';
    $sql='SELECT numeroReservado FROM datos WHERE numeroReservado NOT IN(50,20,34,67)';
    $numerosReservados = mysqli_query($conectar,$sql);         
    while ($filas=mysqli_fetch_assoc($numerosReservados)){
        printf("%s\n",$filas["numeroReservado"]);
    }
```

Así el código estará optimizando, pues no traerías datos para desechar parte de ellos.

Ahora bien, si necesitas también los números reservados para otra cosa, puedes discriminar usando [`in_array()`](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.in-array.php), algo así:

```
<?php

    include 'conexion.php';
    $keyNumbers = array(50,20,34,67);

    $sql='SELECT numeroReservado FROM datos';
    $numerosReservados = mysqli_query($conectar,$sql);         
    while ($filas=mysqli_fetch_assoc($numerosReservados)){
        $num=$filas["numeroReservado"];
        if (in_array($num, $keyNumbers)) {
            printf("%s\n",$num);
        } else {
            #Es reservado, hacer lo que haga falta
        }
    }
```

Comment: Genial! El hecho es que los datos serán dinámicos y podrán variar dependiendo de la base de datos a la que se conecte el programa. Muchas gracias a ti también! :)